# For loop in a while loop in Python creates several files and keeps overwriting them with data?

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, while-loop

So, I currently have a code that runs without errors (Yay!).

However, the serial data is writing to only two text files.  (serial0.txt and serial1.txt).  I want it to run consistently (I have a pause button) by creating up to 11 files, placing/reading data in each one then overwriting the same 11 text files once the while loop recommences.

Background:  It is a lot of data.  I want to pull up a text file after pausing to see it; but as of now, I don't wish to keep all the data files I am creating.  Hence, the creation of only a few text files.

CODE: (I only pasted the stuff I thought would be relevant, but I will paste more if needed)

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1)

ser.stopbits = 2
  #pack actually displays it in the window


def get_data():

    namerange = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
    while True:

        for i in namerange:

            f = open("serial" + str(i) + ".txt", 'w+')             
            #f = open("serial%d.txt") % i
            data=ser.readline()
            f.write(str(data))
            f.close()


            lines = open("serial" + str(i) + ".txt", 'r+')

            read_serial=lines.readline()

            mylist = [int(x) for x in read_serial.split(',') if x.strip().isdigit()]
            x = np.linspace(340, 850, num=len(mylist))
            ax1.clear()
            lines.close()
            ax1.plot(x, mylist)
            plt.ylim([0, 1000])
            return x, mylist
```

Comment: don't use `f.close()` if you're using `with open()` also fix your indentation (I'm assuming it's just from copy - pasting to S.O. otherwise you'd be getting a syntax error)

Comment: also, using `f.write(data)` is preferred over `print(data, file=f)` and is considered much more consistent as far as handling of encodings, and writing binary data.

Comment: Yikes. `xrange` as a variable name is somewhat confusing for people familiar with Python 2.

Comment: If that is indeed the indentation you're using, A: the inconsistency of copying to S.O. is probably from mixing spaces and tabs (which you shouldn't do) B: you are returning from the function `get_data()` before any of your loops can "loop" back so only one iteration is ever executed

Comment: Sorry for the indentation (copied it over wrong/spaces to make it code format).  I have had a lot of trouble with this code as far as getting it to read the way I want it to and print into a text file.  What appears before you is the mess that came out of lots of beginner troubleshooting...  :/  I can make those changes.  How do I fix the returning problem?  The data is currently graphing (the def get_data is executed via a button click).  I thought "return" got me the data.  But, is it also returning from the function?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone in the future would like to know this, this is what I ended up doing, and it WORKS!

```
from tkinter import *
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time
import io
import serial
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import sys
import random
from threading import Thread

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=1) #define data incoming     from the serial port

ser.stopbits = 2
  #pack actually displays it in the window


def samples():

    namerange = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
    for i in namerange:
        print (i)    
        f = open("serial" + str(i) + ".txt", 'w+')#encoding='utf-8')              
        #f = open("serial%d.txt") % (i)
        data=ser.readline() #read the defined serial import
        f.write(str(data)) #place data into the text file
        f.close() #close the text file


        lines = open("serial" + str(i) + ".txt", 'r+')#, encoding='utf-8')      #open that same text file (reading priviledges)

        read_serial=lines.readline() #read the text file
        global mylist
        mylist = [int(x) for x in read_serial.split(',') if x.strip().isdigit()] #make the read data an interger and strip it of any data     that is not a number (comma, ending/beginning letters)
        global x
        x = np.linspace(340, 850, num=len(mylist)) #creation of x axis
        ax1.clear()
        lines.close() #close the text file
        ax1.plot(x, mylist)
        plt.ylim([0, 1000])
    return x, mylist

def f():
    while True: samples()
    Thread(target=f).start()


Thread(target=f).start()


def get_data():
    global mylist
    global x
    return x, mylist # put it on the graph
```

Then, my graphing "start" button only calls the "get_data" function.  So, the thread runs in the background, but I only see it'd output on the graph when I hit the button.  This is a very round about, messy way I think, but I am satisfied with it.